# Breaking List value with space delimiter - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to break each list value as shown below into two variables with space as its delimiter. But i am not able to do so in Lists. Is there any better way to do it? Kindly let me know.

```
 List1 = ['help  show this help message and exit','file  Output to the text file']

 for i in range(strlist.__len__()):
      # In this loop I want to break each list into two variables i.e. help, show this help message and exit in two separate string variables. 
      print(strlist[i])
```

Comment: Side note: Python comments starts with `#` generally or `'''` for block of comments

Comment: If you want a list of pairs you can use a comprehension  `[(a, b) for a, b in (s.split(None, 1) for s in List1)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split by first space(s) with [`split(None, 1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> for item in List1:
...     print(item.split(None, 1))
... 
['help', 'show this help message and exit']
['file', 'Output to the text file']
```

You can then *unpack* the result into separate variables, if needed:

```
>>> for item in List1:
...     key, value = item.split(None, 1)
...     print(key)
...     print(value)
... 
help
show this help message and exit
file
Output to the text file
```

Comment: If you split by two spaces `split("  ", 1)` then you will not have that annoying single space indent.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's much better, updated accordingly. Thank you!